# How to replace text inside span inside anchor inside div in jquery

Tags: jquery

how to replace Sunday,Monday,Tuesday.. with SUN,MON,TUE... in the below table using JQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<table> 
<tr>
<th><div> <div id="xyz"> <a href="www.google.com"> 20 may
<span>Sunday</span> </a> </div></div></th>
<th><div> <div id="xyz"> <a
href="www.google.com"> 21 may <span>Monday</span> </a> </div></div> </th>
<th><div> <div id="xyz"> <a href="www.google.com"> 22 may
<span>Tuesday</span> </a> </div> </div></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

By
Nani

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Did you realise you have duplicate IDs?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
var days = {
    'Sunday': 'SUN',
    'Monday': 'MON'
    /* ... */
};

$('span').text(function(i, day) {
    return days[day] || day;
});
```

If there is no match, it won't update the `span`.

Comment: how to change Sunday to SUN using id="xyz"

Comment: @Nanigandham If you mean to simply target `#xyz`, just change the selector in my example.

Comment: do i need to use  each loop to replace entire table it is not working alex

Comment: @Nanigandham You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute.

Comment: do i need to use each loop or what?